# Finding the $1000$-th decimal of $\sqrt{1111...111}$

Tags: calculus, radicals, decimal-expansion

As I was cleaning up my desk, I found my Calculus exam from almost a year ago. I remember there was only a bonus task that required either a tad more wit, either a bit more time. It goes like this :

---

> $$ \text{Find the 1000-th  decimal of }\underbrace{\sqrt{1111...111}}_{1998 \text{ times}} . $$

---

I remember noticing $11 = \frac{10^2-1}{9}$, building up a general case upon this observation and representing it via series using the  binomial theorem, but nothing actually led me to the actual answer.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You could compute this mess, using Maple. However it would be a cumbersome task.

Comment: Note this was a single task out of a total of $10$, in an exam that allowed no other instruments than pen and paper. I'm interested in a solution, I couldn't care less about the actual digit

Comment: Only as a bonus task. Other subjects were quite approachable by using conventional techniques taught in Calculus 3.

Comment: Calculus III?! What?!

Comment: This was in your exam? Talk about hard-core Calculus :O

Comment: @Aleksandar what's the confusion about ?

Comment: @Victor Confusion, I don't think so. I am just awed that such a question was on a Calc III exam, even as a bonus.

Comment: Well we could approximate that number as $10/9 \times 10^{1998}$ and then we'd get the square root, $\sqrt {10}/3 \times 10^{994}$ and then you could try to find the $1000$-th decimal digit.

Comment: Here's some food for thought... Compare $\sqrt{11}\approx 3.3$ with $\sqrt{1111}\approx33.33$ with $\sqrt{111111}\approx333.333$. Then we expect that $3$ is our answer.

Comment: Using an unproved rule that I have observed, I would say that the result is (0.33333333...+ the number 3 repated 333 times (as in 33333.....to 333 digits). So the last integer digit would be 3.

Comment: @Aleksandar We have $x = 10^{1996}\left(\frac {10}3\right)^2 + \frac 19$, so all digits of $\sqrt{x-\frac19}$ are $3$'s. One just needs to compare $\sqrt{x-\frac19}$ and $\sqrt{x}$

Comment: @zahbaz, exactly my point!

Comment: That depends on the interpretation of "decimal". It could be the digit corresponding to the position $10^{-1000}$, i.e., the 1000th digit of the fractional part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you get
$$
\frac13\sqrt{10^{1998}-1}=\frac13·10^{999}·\sqrt{1-10^{-1998}}
$$
and by the binomial series
$$
\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac12x -\frac18x^2+\frac1{16}x^3-\frac{5}{128}x^4\pm…
$$
it is only the first three terms that influence the first 4000 or so digits leading to
\begin{align}
\frac13·10^{999}·(1-5·10^{-1999}-1.25·10^{-3997}-…)
&=\frac13·10^{999}·0.\underbrace{99…9}_{1998}4\underbrace{99…9}_{1997}874999…
\\
&=10^{999}·0.\underbrace{33…3}_{1998}1\underbrace{66…6}_{1997}624999
\end{align}
I'll leave you to find out where the 1000 decimal digit after the point comes to lie. To compare:
\begin{align}
\sqrt{999999}&=999.99949999987499993749996093747265622949217138670565794807…
\\
\sqrt{111111}&=333.33316666662499997916665364582421874316405712890188598269…
\\
\sqrt{99999999}&=9999.99994999999987499999937499999609374997265624979492187338…
\\
\sqrt{11111111}&=3333.33331666666662499999979166666536458332421874993164062446…
\end{align}