# Find the thousandth digit after the decimal point of $\sqrt N$ if N-

Tags: number-theory, repunit-numbers

Let N be a positive integer with 1998 decimal digits, all of them 1,that is-
$$N=1111......11$$
Find the thousandth digit after the decimal point of $\sqrt N$

Comment: What have you tried?  Alpha will solve it in an instant.

Comment: It has to be solved without use of any calculator or mobile phone.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you have a nice expression for $N$?  Have you tried to take the square root of it?

Comment: After thinking for a while I was not able to understand it so I skipped this question.

Comment: Hint: $N=\dfrac{10^{1998}-1}{9}.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the $1000$th digit after the decimal point of $\sqrt{n},$ where $n=\underbrace{11\dots1}_{1998 \text{ 1's}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3411118/find-the-1000th-digit-after-the-decimal-point-of-sqrtn-where-n-underbr)

Comment: I noticed the duplicate question number (3411118) has a string of `1`s!

Comment: [Another duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1464421/finding-the-1000-th-decimal-of-sqrt1111-111)

Comment: So  $N=\frac{10^{2k}}9 - \frac 19$ and $\sqrt N\approx\frac 13 10^k$.  If we let $\sqrt N=3333......3.333333 - \epsilon$ we've got $-\frac 19 - 2*33333.33333\epsilon + \epsilon^2 = 0$. Or $-\frac 3-2*99999.999999\epsilon + 3\epsilon^2$. Solving for $\epsilon$ and estimating for the first $k, k+1, k+2$ digits is probably not difficult.